# SQL Table column to be used in querying the same table

Tags: sql, nested

I am having the following issue in relation to an table in my DB.

I have the following user table (`usertable1`) that has the following columns:

```
table_id row_id name   changed_by_value department      lastlogon  lastlogoff
1000     1      Admin  1                main_department 10-16-2013 10-16-2013
1000     2      User2  1                main_department 10-16-2013 10-16-2013
1000     3      User3  1                main_department 10-16-2013 10-16-2013
1000     4      User4  1                main_department 10-16-2013 10-16-2013
1000     5      User5  1                main_department 10-16-2013 10-16-2013
```

The `changed_by_value` column is a numeric and is has an associated entry in the `row_id` column e.g.

User2 was last changed by the Admin user as the `changed_by_value = 1`.

What i would like to do is rather than having the numeric `changed_by_value` in the SQL query results, I'd like to have the name of that user i.e. Admin.

I've tried various ways of doing this but to no avail to date:

```
select a.table_id, a.row_id, a.name, a.department, a.lastlogon, a.lastlogoff, 
(select b.name from usertable1 as b where a.changed_by_value = b.row_id) 
from usertable1 as a
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe you're just looking for a self join, so try this:

```
SELECT 
  a.table_id, a.row_id, a.name, a.department, 
  a.lastlogon, a.lastlogoff, 
  b.name AS 'Changed by'
FROM usertable1 AS a
INNER JOIN usertable1 AS b ON a.changed_by_value = b.row_id
```

Comment: @user2887709 If my answer was useful please consider accepting it so the question gets marked as answered. :)